# What is WCF in .NET?

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf

What is WCF and WF in .NET? What are its uses? How to start learning it?

Thanks for  answers, they are great guideline for me. But I want to ask where should I use thins WCF service? In which scenario we can use it properly?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

WCF = Windows Communication Foundation

A communication-oriented set of APIs and a "runtime" inside .NET to make two (or more) systems talk to one another. It basically replaces ASMX (ASP.NET web services), .NET remoting (object remoting) and a few other communication-related API's and products in the .NET space.

[image: What does WCF replace?]

It can and should be used any time two systems (apps, machines) need to exchange information, basically. It's the foundation for all "connected systems".

Your ultimate destination is the [MSDN Developer Center for WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/WCF) which has a ton of tutorials, articles, sample code, screen casts, videos and much more.

Comment: thanks...just now i started learning wcf and your answer was very helpful for me to know the concept

Answer (score 9):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx): 
"*Windows Communication Foundation is...
a part of the .NET Framework that provides a unified programming model for rapidly building service-oriented applications that communicate across the web and the enterprise.*"

[White Paper on WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-se/library/dd943056%28en-us%29.aspx)

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

I have only a couple of articles here, but they are simple: http://www.singingeels.com/?Category=WCF

Answer (score 3):

The Windows Communication Foundation (or WCF) is an application programming interface (API) in the .NET Framework for building connected, service-oriented applications.

WCF is meant for designing and deploying distributed applications under service-oriented architecture (SOA) implementation. ** Architechture

Answer (score 2):

WCF is stand for Windows Communication Foundation. This is great network distributed system developed by Microsoft for communication between applications.Here you can find the good tutorial about WCF.

http://www.wcftutorial.net/

Answer (score 2):

From WikiPedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation):

> The Windows Communication Foundation (or WCF) is an application
>   programming interface (API) in the .NET Framework for building
>   connected, service-oriented applications.
>
> WCF is meant for designing and deploying distributed applications
>   under service-oriented architecture (SOA) implementation.
>   ** Architechture
>
> ** WCF is designed using service oriented architecture principles to
>   support distributed computing where services have remote consumers.
>   Clients can consume multiple services; services can be consumed by
>   multiple clients. Services are loosely coupled to each other. Services
>   typically have a WSDL interface (Web Services Description Language)
>   that any WCF client can use to consume the service, regardless of
>   which platform the service is hosted on. WCF implements many advanced
>   Web services (WS) standards such as WS-Addressing,
>   WS-ReliableMessaging and WS-Security. With the release of .NET
>   Framework 4.0, WCF also provides RSS Syndication Services,
>   WS-Discovery, routing and better support for REST services.
>   **Endpoint** A WCF client connects to a WCF service via an Endpoint.
>   Each service exposes its contract via one or more endpoints. An
>   endpoint has an address (which is a URL specifying where the endpoint
>   can be accessed) and binding properties that specify how the data will
>   be transferred.

Answer (score 2):

WCF Stands for Windows Communication Foundation. Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) is a framework for building service-oriented applications in .Net. Its an Microsoft Answer to SOA.

Get more interview questions on WCF at: http://interviewmantra.com/category/Windows-Communication-Foundation-(WCF).aspx